# What is this weird directory in my PATH on my Mac, (running latest macOS Ventura)?

Tags: terminal, path, macos

I found that my PATH on my MacBook Pro running Mac OS Ventura 13.0.1 has a strange directory inside all of the normal ones, i.e. /opt/homebrew/bin:/usr/local/bin:XXX:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:

**/System/Cryptexes/App/usr/bin** is inserted into my PATH at the point with XXX

As noted from the command: *echo $PATH*

1. Where is it coming from?
2. Is it safe to keep?
3. Is it okay to remove from PATH?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

> Where is it coming from?
> Is it safe to keep?
> Is it okay to remove from PATH?

The `/System/Cryptexes` directories are part of [macOS security](https://eclecticlight.co/2022/11/16/cryptex-how-a-custom-iphone-is-changing-macos-updates/). Mostly Safari and a few other features use it.

So it came from Apple, it is safe to keep, and if you don't use anything in there, it is likely safe to remove.

Comment: Thanks for that link. That definitely helped curb my curiosity.
I will probably leave it as it isn't really hurting anything.

Comment: That specific PATH entry is the location of ```safaridriver```, which is used for browser testing with Selenium.

Comment: @RCross could you clarify what path you are referring? Are you suggesting Apple ships a Selenium component?

Comment: The only file I see from `ls -l /System/Cryptexes/App/usr/bin/` is safaridriver:  `-rwxr-xr-x  1 root  wheel  134304 Feb  9  2023 safaridriver`

Answer (score 4):

> 1. Where is it coming from?

from: /etc/paths

[Solid explanation](https://golangbyexample.com/understand-etc-paths-pathsd-mac/) of /etc/paths file and /etc/paths.d directory